# Renomear métodos de importações?

Tags: javascript, react, característica-linguagem

Primeiramente gostaria de saber se posso chamar elementos que importamos **de métodos**, ou seja:

```
import { Icon, Button, cabecalho : Header} from 'semantic-ui-react'
```

Eu poderia chamar Icon, Button ou Header de métodos?
Feito esse questionamento gostaria de saber se é possível fazer uma renomeação desse "método" como por exemplo esse header para um de minha preferência. Estou tendo um problema em relação a isso e gostaria de saber se é possível ou se existe alguma forma fazer com que tenha duas "coisas" com o mesmo nome mas que fazem coisas diferentes.

[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]

Comment: Por favor, **[edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/460376/edit)** a sua pergunta para remover o código em imagem. Conforme você pode ler [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485), código como imagem não é uma boa prática neste site.

Answer (score 5):

Como você está utilizando os `import`s especificados pelo ECMAScript 2015, você pode os renomear usando a notação `as`, assim:

```
import { Foo } from 'foo-module';

typeof Foo; // "function", por exemplo.
```

Para:

```
import { Foo as CustomName } from 'foo-module';
// `CustomName` é agora um *alias* para `Foo` (que deixa de estar no escopo).

typeof Foo; // "undefined"
typeof CustomName; // "function", por exemplo.
```

Para saber mais, não deixe de consultar a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

---

Em relação à nomenclatura, só fazer parte de uma importação não é possível classificá-los como métodos, já que o ECMAScript define que qualquer valor pode ser exportado por um módulo X.

Nesse caso, contudo, é possível afirmar que são "componentes React" (que não é um nome padronizado pelo ECMAScript, mas que nos permite concluir que se trata de uma *classe* ou *função*).

Comment: Muito obrigado!